# Can a US permanent Resident with an expiring Filipino passport traveling to Mexico be denied?

Tags: air-travel, filipino-citizens, mexico-city, us-permanent-residents

I am a US permanent resident with a Filipino passport and I will be traveling from US to Mexico City on March 13th. I just looked at my Filipino passport and saw that it expires on March 14th - one day after I land in Mexico. Would I have any trouble leaving/entering US or Mexico? I read online that I may not need a valid passport to enter the US because of my permanent residence card and that Mexico does not require a 6-month valid passport just valid on entry. Just wondering if anyone here may have answers. Thanks!

Comment: Mexico *probably* requires the passport to be valid for the duration of your stay, but I'm not sure.  You certainly do not require a passport to return to the US.

Answer (score 2):

You can enter the US with only your green card; a passport is not required.

As for entering Mexico: Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states that you need both the passport and green card, but the passport only needs to be valid on the day you arrive.

The relevant bits:

> Passport required.
>
> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid on arrival.
> - Warning: if departing from the USA (regardless of any  destination passport exemptions), a valid passport and/or accepted departure
>     document is required by the US immigration authorities.
>
> Passport Exemptions:
>
> - Nationals of Philippines with an emergency passport.
>
> Admission and Transit Restrictions:
>
> - Passports must be machine readable to enter and transit.
> - This does not apply to passengers with an emergency or a temporary passport.
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers with a Permanent Resident or
>   Resident Alien Card (Form I-551) issued by USA for a maximum stay of
>   180 days.